# How to reference diffirent type of figures (i.e. "figures" and "plates")

Tags: floats, xetex, cross-referencing, labels, cleveref

I would like to add 2 types of figures in my document (with different counters)

1. Figures
2. Plates (if general, would be possible to differentiate between B&W, Color plates...)

I don't understand which environment I have to customize (figures? refs? labels?).

Reason: All drawings should be named `fig. XX` and are in the text. Photos should be placed at the end and referenced as `pl. XX`. [For curiosity] it would be nice to distinguish B&W photos `pl. XX` from color `c. pl. XX`.

An example of rendered text could be:

```
From the diagram (fig. 1, p. 1), the X-Ray imagery (pl. 1, p. 32)
or the colored tomography (c. pl. 1, p. 104), we deduce that ....
```

`fig. 1`, `pl. 1` and `c. pl. 1` are three different images included with

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=10mm]{fig_1}
\label{fig_1}
\end{figure} 

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=10mm]{pl_1}
\label{pl_1}
\end{figure} 

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=10mm]{c_pl_1}
\label{c_pl_1}
\end{figure}
```

I use `xelatex` and the packages `varioref, hyperref, cleveref` in this order (as specified in `cleverref` manual, 12.1, p. 23). My document use different languages (English, French, German) but all the references should be "fig/pl." (i.e. no translation into "Abb.").

Comment: Your labels won't do what you intend them to do without a `\caption`, correct would be `\caption{<text>\label{fig_1}}` for example.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your objectives: (a) you want to create a new float type called, say, `plate`, and the `plate` counter should be separate from and independent of the `figure` counter. (b) The `plate` float type may need to consist of two subtypes, one for B&W images, the other for color images. (c) Cross-references to these objects should use the prefixes `fig.` and `pl.`, repectively. Please advise if I missed something.

Comment: @Mico 3 independent different types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want separate and independent counters for figures and two types of "plates", I think you should employ the machinery of the `newfloat` package to create two new floating environments, called (say) `bwplate` and `clrplate`. Then, use `\crefname` directives to inform `cleveref` which prefix labels to use when running `\cref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.

\usepackage{newfloat} % for '\DeclareFloatingEnvironment' macro
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name=Plate]{bwplate} % or 'name=B\&W Plate'
%% declare labels for use with \cref:
\crefname{bwplate}{b\&w pl.}{b\&w pls.}
\Crefname{bwplate}{B\&W Plate}{B\&W Plates}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name=Color Plate]{clrplate}
%% declare labels for use with \cref:
\crefname{clrplate}{clr. pl.}{clr. pls.}
\Crefname{clrplate}{Color Plate}{Color Plates}


\begin{document}

Cross-references to \cref{fig:1,pl:1,cpl:1,pl:2,cpl:2}.

\Cref{fig:1}. \Cref{pl:1,pl:2}. \Cref{cpl:1,cpl:2}.


\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{fig_1}
\caption{A graphic}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure} 
\begin{bwplate}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{pl_1}
\caption{A first B\&W image}\label{pl:1}
\end{bwplate} 
\begin{clrplate}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{c_pl_1}
\caption{A first color image}\label{cpl:1}
\end{clrplate} 
\begin{bwplate}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{pl_2}
\caption{A second B\&W image}\label{pl:2}
\end{bwplate} 
\begin{clrplate}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{c_pl_2}
\caption{A second color image}\label{cpl:2}
\end{clrplate} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Discovering package `newfloat`. I was not expecting that options sucht as `[h!]` would be so easily inherited. Fascinating. If you have a reading pointer to learn more, I would take it!

Comment: There's not much "special" or "magical" about the `newfloat` package, really. It just does a very good job... For an in-depth discussion of how LaTeX places floating environments, please see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5001) Well worth the read!